# How to change all text in textNodes after entering

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to change all text in DOMnodes with entered text in my input.
How I can do it?

```
$('#lc-change-all-values').keyup(function(){
     $('body *').text($(this).val())// How I can do it?
});
```

This code should be allowed on any web page. I worked with google chrome extension. My HTML:

```
<h1>BrowsingData API Sample</h1>
<div role="main">
  <form>
    <label for="timeframe">Remove all browsing data from:</label>
    <select id="timeframe">
      <option value="hour">the past hour</option>
      <option value="day">the past day</option>
      <option value="week">the past week</option>
      <option value="4weeks">the past four weeks</option>
      <option value="forever">the beginning of time</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button">OBLITERATE!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I need to get html code like this:

```
<h1>My text</h1>
<div role="main">
  <form>
    <label for="timeframe">My text</label>
    <select id="timeframe">
      <option value="hour">My text</option>
      <option value="day">My text</option>
      <option value="week">My text</option>
      <option value="4weeks">My text</option>
      <option value="forever">My text</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button">My text</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? `js` at Question not returning expected results ?

Answer (score 0):

Note, `#lc-change-all-values` not appear at `html` ?

Added `<input type="text" id="lc-change-all-values" />` to `html` ; specifically selected elements where `#lc-change-all-values` `value` would be set as utilizing `.text()`

```js
$("#lc-change-all-values").keyup(function() {
  $("h1, button, label, select option")
  .text(this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="lc-change-all-values" />
  <h1>BrowsingData API Sample</h1>
  <div role="main">
    <form>
      <label for="timeframe">Remove all browsing data from:</label>
      <select id="timeframe">
        <option value="hour">the past hour</option>
        <option value="day">the past day</option>
        <option value="week">the past week</option>
        <option value="4weeks">the past four weeks</option>
        <option value="forever">the beginning of time</option>
      </select>
      <button id="button">OBLITERATE!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @StasKh `#lc-change-all-values` not appear at `html` ?

Comment: @StasKh Is `#lc-change-all-values` an `<input>` element ?